# Zustand persist middleware overwrites persist store with initial state

Tags: react-native, persist, zustand

I'm 100% certain this is a problem I am causing but not sure how to fix.
I have a store with user settings that I would like to persist (I am using MMKV as store). On the app I set the settings both TRUE and can see that my MMKV store is getting the updates but then when I close and open or refresh the app, it looks like, from what I can tell that my store is getting set with the initial values I set in my zustand state.

I tested this by removing the initial state, which produces this:

```json
{
  "version": 1
}
```

then setting my settings on the app, which produces this:

```json
{
    "state": {
      "notifications": {
        "bookings": false,
        "messages": false
      }
    },
    "version": 1
}
```

but then when I reload the app it reverts back to the first result which is why I think it is setting the store from the initial state.

Can anyone spot a problem here?

```js
const initialState = {
  settings: {
    notifications: {
      bookings: false,
      messages: false,
    },
  },
};

const zustandStorage: StateStorage = {
  setItem: (name, value) => {
    return storage.set(name, value);
  },
  getItem: (name) => {
    let value = storage.getString(name);
    return value ?? null;
  },
  removeItem: (name) => {
    return storage.delete(name);
  },
};

const storage = zustandSorage.getItem('user_settings');

export const createSettingsSlice: StateCreator<
  Settings,
  [],
  [['zustand/persist', unknown]]
> = persist(
  (set, get) => ({
    ...initialState,
    setInitialState: () => {
      checkNotifications()
        .then(async ({ status }) => {
          if (status === 'granted') {
              set(
                produce((state) => {
                  (state.settings.notifications.bookings =
                    storage?.state.notifications.bookings),
                    (state.settings.notifications.messages =
                      storage?.state.notifications.messages);
                })
              );
            }
          } else {
            set(
              produce((state) => {
                (state.settings.notifications.bookings = false),
                  (state.settings.notifications.messages = false);
              })
            );
          }
        });
    },
    setNotification: (value: 'MESSAGES' | 'BOOKINGS') => {
      set(
              produce((state) => {
                (state.settings.notifications.bookings =
                  value === 'BOOKINGS'
                    ? !state.settings.notifications.bookings
                    : state.settings.notifications.bookings),
                  (state.settings.notifications.messages =
                    value === 'MESSAGES'
                      ? !state.settings.notifications.messages
                      : state.settings.notifications.messages);
              })
            );
    },
    resetNotification: () => {
      set(() => initialState);
    },
  }),
  {
    name: 'user_settings',
    storage: createJSONStorage(() => zustandStorage),
    partialize: (state) => state.settings,
    version: 1
  }
);
```